# PowerShell: Add Array with mutliple values to value field in JSON

Tags: arrays, json, rest, powershell

I have some restmethods with powershell (VMWare vRA API) where I get a template for a development request and then I need to fill that (JSON format).
The "data" part of the template has different properties like:

```
Name                  : Test
selectedNetworks      : 
selectedServices      :
```

My question:
How do I get my array $networks (network1,network2,network3) to fill the json element "selectedNetworks" that it becomes like this:

```
"key":  "selectedNetworks",
"value":  {
"type":  "multiple",
"elementTypeId":  "STRING",
"items":  [
    {
        "type":  "string",
        "value":  "network1"
    },
    {
        "type":  "string",
        "value":  "network2"
    },
    {
        "type":  "string",      
        "value":  "network3"
    }
  ]
}
```

I know how to add in "simple" values like the name is
    $WebRequestBodyData.Name="$Name"
But how do I get the complex format above into $WebRequestBodyData.selectedNetworks?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Thanks and best regards,
Ville

Comment: Have you tried looking into this? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertto-json?view=powershell-6

Answer (score 0):

I could solve it like that:

```
$networkjson = '{"type":  "multiple", "elementTypeId":  "STRING", "items":  [] }' | ConvertFrom-Json
foreach($nwitem in $networks){
    $networkjson.items += $nwitem
}
$BodyData.selectedNetworks += $networkjson
```